# NSFilemanager copy file issue on 10.9

Tags: osx-yosemite, nsurl, osx-mountain-lion, nsfilemanager, appstore-sandbox

I have been developing an application on my first computer which works on mac os 10.8. App needs to copy files from one directory to another directory. This scenerio does work suitable on my first computer. But same application does not copy files to another directory on my second computer which works on mac os 10.9.

I tried to open Sandbox (Certainly I'm not sure how Sandbox works) then Application works well on my second computer but not on first computer. When I close Sandbox, then Application works well on my First computer but not second computer.:(

What must I do in order to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the sandbox design guideline. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html